# Redshift: Combining GETDATE and Interval function

Tags: intervals, amazon-redshift, getdate

I want to only pull results that correspond to todays date. I am new to Redshift but am familiar with MYSQL. The closest I can get is 24 hours but I would prefer to use only data from today, I have been using:

```
 history_date >= date(GETDATE())- Interval '24 hours'
```

Would using the current date function be another alternative? Here is is entire query in case any one is interested :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to [use the DATE_TRUNC function to get the date with the time portion removed](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_TRUNC.html).

```
history_date >= date(DATE_TRUNC('day', GETDATE()))
```